# What is granularity in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

What is granularity in particle physics? It is used throughout "The ATLAS Experiment at the CERN Large Hadron Collider" http://nordberg.web.cern.ch/PAPERS/JINST08.pdf without being defined anywhere.

An example use: "high detector granularity is needed to handle the particle fluxes and to reduce the influence of overlapping events"

Resolution would simply be referred to as "resolution" so it can't be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [instrumentation](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1017827/files/p209.pdf) review:

> Next follow the detectors, whose key parameters are efficiency,  speed, granularity and resolution.

The term is used and  not defined further because it is descriptive of the "number of sensitive to measurement ΔV(ΔxΔyΔz)  per unit volume : how many "grains" and what a "grain" is will depend on the material and design composing the specific detector.

See fig 32. That is one "grain" in  the silicon detector.